# CS50 Week5 Speller compiles but is incorrect. Also takes no time on size and unload

Tags: c++, c, cs50

I started working on this yesterday. It compiles but whenever I run it with

> ./speller texts/lalaland.txt

I get this result:

```
WORDS MISSPELLED:     17134
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  143091
WORDS IN TEXT:        17756
TIME IN load:         0.04
TIME IN check:        8.41
TIME IN size:         0.00
TIME IN unload:       0.00
TIME IN TOTAL:        8.45
```

As you can see it takes a stupid amount of time in **"check"** and no time in **"size"** or **"unload"**. I'm almost certain there's nothing wrong with my check function though. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
    // Implements a dictionary's functionality
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "dictionary.h"
    #include <strings.h>
    unsigned int counter;
    unsigned int i;
    // Represents a node in a hash table
    typedef struct node
    {
        char word[LENGTH + 1];
        struct node *next;
    }
    node;

    // TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
    const unsigned int N = 26;

    // Hash table
    node *table[N];

    // Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
    bool check(const char *word)
    {
        i = hash(word);

        node *cursor = table[i];

        while (cursor != 0)
        {
            if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Hashes word to a number
    unsigned int hash(const char *word)
    {
        int value;
        for (int j = 0; j< strlen(word); j++)
        {
            value = value + tolower(word[j]);
        }
        return (value % N);
    }

    // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
    bool load(const char *dictionary)
    {
        // TODO
        FILE* file = fopen(dictionary, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        char word[LENGTH + 1];

        while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
        {
            node *new = malloc(sizeof(node));

            if (new == NULL)
            {
                return false;
            }

            strcpy(new->word, word);
            new->next = NULL;

            i = hash(word);
            new->next = table[i];
            table[i] = new;
            counter++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }

    // Returns number of words in a dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
    unsigned int size(void)
    {
        if (counter != 0)
        {
            return counter;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
    bool unload(void)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            node *head = table[j];
            node *cursor = head;
            node *temp = head;

            while(cursor != NULL)
            {
                cursor = cursor->next;
                free(temp);
                temp = cursor;
            }
            if (cursor == NULL)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the `hash` function. valgrind will complain about an unitialised value in hash; specifically `value`. Because `value` is not initialized, it will have the value that is stored in the memory that is assigned to it. Unpredictable results ensue.

There is also a problem with unload. Once the first node is freed, program will return `true` from the unload function. However, it hasn't freed any other nodes.